# Textfile created in PHP has the page code in it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get data from a table, write them in a file using PHP and force the download, but whenever I download the file, it always has the code of the page plus what I want in the file.

Can you see what is wrong with my PHP code

```
<?php


if (empty($_POST['file'])) {

    echo "<div>";
    echo "<h1 align='center'>ERROR:</h1>";
    echo "<p align='center'>Something is missing, please go back and check your error!</p>";
    echo "<div class='error' width='50%' height='50%' align='center'><img src='./images/error.png'/></div>";
    echo "</div>";  
}


else {

    $filename=$_POST['file'];

    $start1=$_POST['line1_start'];
    $stop1=$_POST['line1_stop'];
    $segment1=$_POST['line1_segment']; 

    $start2=$_POST['line2_start'];
    $stop2=$_POST['line2_stop'];
    $segment2=$_POST['line2_segment'];

    $start3=$_POST['line3_start'];
    $stop3=$_POST['line3_stop'];
    $segment3=$_POST['line3_segment'];


    $start4=$_POST['line4_start'];
    $stop4=$_POST['line4_stop'];
    $segment4=$_POST['line4_segment'];


    $start5=$_POST['line5_start'];
    $stop5=$_POST['line5_stop'];
    $segment5=$_POST['line5_segment'];




    $start6=$_POST['line6_start'];
    $stop6=$_POST['line6_stop'];
    $segment6=$_POST['line6_segment'];

    $start7=$_POST['line7_start'];
    $stop7=$_POST['line7_stop'];
    $segment7=$_POST['line7_segment'];

    $start8=$_POST['line8_start'];
    $stop8=$_POST['line8_stop'];
    $segment8=$_POST['line8_segment'];

    $start9=$_POST['line9_start'];
    $stop9=$_POST['line9_stop'];
    $segment9=$_POST['line9_segment'];

    $start10=$_POST['line10_start'];
    $stop10=$_POST['line10_stop'];
    $segment10=$_POST['line10_segment'];

    $start11=$_POST['line11_start'];
    $stop11=$_POST['line11_stop'];
    $segment11=$_POST['line11_segment'];

    $start12=$_POST['line12_start'];
    $stop12=$_POST['line12_stop'];
    $segment12=$_POST['line12_segment'];

    $start13=$_POST['line13_start'];
    $stop13=$_POST['line13_stop'];
    $segment13=$_POST['line13_segment'];

    $start14=$_POST['line14_start'];
    $stop14=$_POST['line14_stop'];
    $segment14=$_POST['line14_segment'];

    $start15=$_POST['line15_start'];
    $stop15=$_POST['line15_stop'];
    $segment15=$_POST['line15_segment'];

    $start16=$_POST['line16_start'];
    $stop16=$_POST['line16_stop'];
    $segment16=$_POST['line16_segment'];

    $start17=$_POST['line17_start'];
    $stop17=$_POST['line17_stop'];
    $segment17=$_POST['line17_segment'];

    $start18=$_POST['line18_start'];
    $stop18=$_POST['line18_stop'];
    $segment18=$_POST['line18_segment'];

    $start19=$_POST['line19_start'];
    $stop19=$_POST['line19_stop'];
    $segment19=$_POST['line19_segment'];

    $start20=$_POST['line20_start'];
    $stop20=$_POST['line20_stop'];
    $segment20=$_POST['line20_segment'];

    $ofile=fopen($filename,'w');
    fwrite($ofile,"1".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start1);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop1.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment1.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"2".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start2);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop2.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment2.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"3".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start3);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop3.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment3.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"4".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start4);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop4.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment4.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"5".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start5);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop5.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment5.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"6".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start6);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop6.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment6.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"7".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start7);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop7.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment7.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"8".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start8);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop8.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment8.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"9".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start9);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop9.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$$segment9.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"10".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start10);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop10.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment10.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"11".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start11);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop11.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment11.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"12".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start12);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop12.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment12.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"13".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start13);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop13.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment13.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"14".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start14);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop14.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment14.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"15".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start15);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop15.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment15.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"16".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start16);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop16.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment16.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"17".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start17);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop17.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment17.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"18".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start18);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop18.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment18.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"19".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start19);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$stop19.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment19.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

    fwrite($ofile,"20".PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$start20);
    fwrite($ofile, " --> ");
    fwrite($ofile,$start20.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($ofile,$segment20.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);



    fclose($ofile);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" '.basename($filename).'"');
    header("Content-Type: text/plain; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");


    echo "<h1 align='center'> SUCCESS :</h1>";
    echo "<p align='center'> The transcription has been successfully made, you can download you file by clicking on the";                  
    echo "button below.</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'> Right-click on the button below, click on 'Save link as' </p>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<div class='success' width='50%' height='40%' align='center'><img src='./images/success.png'/></div>";

    readfile($filename);

}

?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do we really need to see half a gazillion lines of repetitive `$startX = ...` code...!?

Comment: It's my first time sharing on stackoverflow, and I am a newbie to this so I have a long way to learn and maybe you can help me correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifically outputting HTML here right before outputting the file:

```
echo "<h1 align='center'> SUCCESS :</h1>";
echo "<p align='center'> The transcription has been successfully made, you can download you file by clicking on the";                  
echo "button below.</p>";
echo "<p align='center'> Right-click on the button below, click on 'Save link as' </p>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<div class='success' width='50%' height='40%' align='center'><img src='./images/success.png'/></div>";
```

If you don't want that to be included in the download, delete it.

**You cannot download a file and show information on the page at the same time.** One click causes one "thing" to download in your browser: *either* a webpage *or* a file that's saved to disk.

If you want to show a "success" and download the file at the same time, one common technique is to output the "success" on the page and then redirect the visitor to the download URL so the download starts immediately. (Usually this sort of page comes with a "your download should be starting now..." message, which everyone hates.)